# Why does Haskell fail to infer type when assigning an existing function identically to a new name?

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference

I am writing prefix names for some of Haskell's infix operators (specifically, +, -, *, /, :, <, <=, >, >=, ==, /=). I wrote the definitions to a file and loaded them into GHCi. At first I wrote each function with two parameters, like

```
geq x y = x >= y
```

which worked for all the operators  listed. Then I tried doing the same thing by just assigning the functions themselves, like

```
geq = (>=)
```

which worked for the arithmetic operators and concatenation, but gave the following error for the comparison operators:

```
test.hs:1:1: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘>=’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Ord a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Ord Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
        instance Ord Integer
          -- Defined in ‘integer-gmp-1.0.0.1:GHC.Integer.Type’
        instance Ord a => Ord (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
        ...plus 22 others
        ...plus five instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • When instantiating ‘geq’, initially inferred to have
      this overly-general type:
        forall a. Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
      NB: This instantiation can be caused by the monomorphism restriction.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Adding a type annotation to the function

```
geq :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
```

(which I took from the GHCi by `:t (>=)`) solves the problem.
Interestingly, GHCi seems OK with the rejected definition if I do it in the interactive prompt, like

```
let geq = (>=)
```

But what about the comparison operators makes Haskell fail to infer the type of `geq = (>=)`, which seems like it wouldn't even need any inference? What algorithm does Haskell use for type inference, and why is GHCi OK with that definition if that isn't valid Haskell without a type annotation?